# What permissions are needed in the Manifest file when reading data from URL to android app?

Tags: android, permissions

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgU3X.png) I need to read some data from a url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Vacoas,Phoenix&destination=Grand+Bassin&key=AIzaSyBDF_8cBD6njbowsWcw6v4etyFY2fKwHSE

and use them for my android app.

Comment: You Need "INTERNET" permission for it.

Comment: i hv that permission already but its still saying "permission denied"

Comment: @aksacha  i added the error log. Do you know what's the matter?

Comment: Are you installing app on emulator or physical device?

Comment: @aksacha on my physical device

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i already hv    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
these 2 but its still saying "permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Are you saving your db or any stuff on your sd card.

Please show your error log

Comment: i added my error log. no im not saving anything on my sd card